# How to add fontAwesome icon to toolbar menu

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, font-awesome

How can I add a icon(fontAwesome) to my toolbar item? Referring to [this link](http://www.johankarlsson.net/2015/09/fontawesome-using-xamarin-forms-and.html), I managed to set a fontawesome to my label. But how do I do that for toolbar itrm?

My code:

```
ToolbarItem Save = new ToolbarItem();
Save.Text = FontAwesome.FAFloppyO;
Save.Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary;
```

I also tried adding icon attribute to my toolbarItem but doesn't work.

Comment: So did it work for you?

Answer (score 4):

I have managed to achieve this out-of-box using [Iconize library](https://github.com/jsmarcus/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Iconize) for Xamarin Forms. It is quite easy to set up.

Now, to save you extra hours of frustrations, you need to:

1. Use IconNavigationPage as parent instead of NavigationPage.
2. Use IconToolbarItem instead of ToolbarItem.
3. The Icon property should be set, not the Text property (i.e. Icon="fa-user")

Let me know if this solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NavigationPage.TitleView](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Navigation/TitleView) instead of Toolbar or Toolbar item.

All you have to do is just adding fontawesome libraries to each platform and than set font familiy property according of target platform.

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Text="&#xf03d;">
        <Button.FontFamily>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                <On Platform="iOS" Value="Font Awesome 5 Free" />
                <On Platform="Android" Value="fa-solid-900.ttf#fa-solid" />
            </OnPlatform>
        </Button.FontFamily>
    </Button>
</StackLayout>
```

this is the one of the basic usage. For better usage you can create your own [static resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries) and apply to button or what ever other items.

This is a code sample from one of my project:

```
<!-- Toolbar -->
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <Grid  HeightRequest="50" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource DarkBackgroundColor}" Margin="0" Padding="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- Title -->
            <Label Text="Inventory" Style="{StaticResource TitleViewTitleLabel}"/>

        <Button Grid.Column="1"  Text="&#xf021;" 
                Style="{StaticResource FontAwesomeButtonRegularTitleViewButton}"
                Command="{Binding SyncDataCommand}"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="2"  Text="&#xf661;"  
                Style="{StaticResource FontAwesomeButtonRegularTitleViewButton}"
                Command="{Binding ShowFunctionalityCommand}"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="3"  Text="&#xf067;" 
                Style="{StaticResource FontAwesomeButtonRegularTitleViewButton}"
                Command="{Binding AddNewInventoryCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```